# take samples from a tuple in tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset

I have a time series features (numpy array) and a labels (same length in time steps and also numpy array). I used tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array() to get tuples of (feature(batched), labels(batched)).

My issue is that I want to split it into training and validation (test is already separate). I want it shuffled and windowed, so I cannot do it before the timeseries_dataset_from_array() method and after, I have a tuple. Can I do:

(train_features, train_labels) = (output_tuple[0].take(num_training_sample), output_tuple[1].take(num_training_sample))

or does this change the order of features and labels?

Update:
What I have is the following

```
#feature of size (2757698, 21, 4, 1) time series array
#labels of size (2757698, 3)

w = (timeseries_dataset_from_array(
          features[:train_size, :, :],
          self.target[:train_size, :], self.WINDOW_SIZE, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1,
          batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, start_index=start,
          end_index=end))


# output is a tuple as a batch of size ((256, 60, 21, 4, 1), (256, 3)), 60 is the window size
```

Output is a generator that you can feed to your model.fit()!

What I need is for this train_dataset to split to train and validation, after shuffle. As you can see, I already picked the test data from the end which is the most recent.

Comment: Can you add code that you tried? The output you get and the expected output.

Comment: I added the simple code that I have. I have the features and labels (both numpy array) and what I need is to window them (sliding window over a period of time), shuffle, break the data into train and validation, batch for training. timeseries_dataset_from_array does all but the split! Any help on how to take care of that?